# Making charts in RaphaelJS that are 100% width?

Tags: raphael

I have seen graphs in Flash & stuff that basically adapt nicely to whatever the size of the browser or flexible element they are inside of.... I'm not really too well versed with raphaelJS but can you do this, and if so, how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In raphaeljs, you can call .setSize on a Raphael object to update its size.  To adapt to runtime changes in browser window size, you can respond to a window resize event.  Using jQuery, you could do:

```
// initialize Raphael object
var w = $(window).width(), 
    h = $(window).height();

var paper = Raphael($("#my_element").get(0), w,h);

$(window).resize(function(){
     w = $(window).width();
     h = $(window).height();
     paper.setSize(w,h);
     redraw_element(); // code to handle re-drawing, if necessary
});
```

Comment: Using `paper.setSize` crops my SVG without scaling it; how would I scale, instead of just cropping?

Answer (score 3):

This will get you a responsive SVG

```
var w = 500, h=500;
var paper = Raphael(w,h);
paper.setViewBox(0,0,w,h,true);
paper.setSize('100%', '100%');
```

Comment: This worked for me. The SVG scaled down when I made the window smaller, but it didn't scale larger; its size was capped at the initial width and height. Also, I specified '100%' only for the width.

Comment: Edit: the 100% height is necessary, or else the height will not change as it scales. It's the equivalent of `height:auto` in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you could set the width to %100 and define a viewBox within SVG. But, Raphael JS manually set a width and height directly on your SVG elements, which kills this technique.

Bosh's answer is great, but it was distorting the aspect ratio for me. Had to tweak a few things to get it working correctly. Also, included some logic to maintain a maximum size.

```
// Variables
var width;
var height;
var maxWidth = 940;
var maxHeight = 600;
var widthPer;

function setSize() {
    // Setup width
    width = window.innerWidth;
    if (width > maxWidth) width = maxWidth;

    // Setup height
    widthPer = width / maxWidth;
    height = widthPer * maxHeight;
}
var paper = Raphael(document.getElementById("infographic"), 940, 600);
paper.setViewBox(0, 0, 940, 600, true);

window.onresize = function(event) {
    setSize();
    paper.setSize(width,height);
    redraw_element();
}
```