# Positioning Raphael SVG paper absolute to container div

Tags: css, svg, raphael

Is there a way to make the Raphael paper object absolute to the div it is in? Thus filling up the div completely? Since the paper I'm working with is relative to its div I'm having a problem with mouse positions during window resizing along with other problems.

Comment: Wondering if this answer would be helpful.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3962926/making-charts-in-raphaeljs-that-are-100-width

Answer (score 0):

If you are also using jquery, maybe you can resize the raphael paper every time the window is resized. You can use jquery `resize()` and then `setSize()` from raphael to do this.

```
$( window ).resize(function() {   

        //get the size of your container div
        var div_width = $("#containerDiv").width();
        var div_height = $("#containerDiv").height();

        paper.setSize(div_width, div_height);
});
```